# C++ Header naming issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm making a project that utilizes RapidJson.
I copy all of the files from RapidJson into my Visual Studio project. When building, I have to add the rapidjson include directory so that there are no errors.

However, this leaves me with an issue.
One of the files in RapidJson is called stream.h. I also have another library copied into my project with the name stream.h. I have to have the include dir inside where the source files are.

What do i do?

Comment: Don't add `.../include/rapidjson` to the include paths, add only `.../include` and do `#include <rapidjson/stream.h>`.

Comment: If I do that, and then I copy the files to my project, then the rapidjson files won't compile because the include path does not include its directory